# Перенос на другой хостинг Bitrix - ошибка TypeError

Tags: php, linux, nginx, битрикс

Сделал резервное копирование, скачал на другой хостинг php8.1, nginx, mariadb.
Настроил nginx:

```
    server {
            listen 80;
            server_name 11.11.11.11;
            root   /var/www/html/bitrixnew/;
            index index.php;
    
             access_log /var/log/nginx/sportmenru5.access.log;
             error_log /var/log/nginx/sportmenru5.error.log;
    
    
            location ~ \.php$ {
                    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            }
            if ($request_uri ~ ^(.*)/index.(html|php)) { return 301 $1/$is_args$args; }
            location / { try_files $uri $uri/ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php$is_args$args;  }
            location ~* @.*\.html$ { internal; }
}
```

Закинул скрипт restore.php в корневой /var/www/html/bitrixnew/
Запустил с браузера, ввёл ссылку на архив с восстановлением, всё установилось, ввёл базу данных и после окончания установки появляется ошибка в браузере по основному адресу сайта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я пытаюсь просто установить чистый Bitrix c помощью скрипта с оф. сайта bitrixsetup.php, то после установки просто белая страница которая доступна по основному адресу.

Тест системы с помощью bitrix-скрипта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу решить эту проблему?

Comment: Ну вообще-то выше написано что требуется конкретная версия PHP, а не самая последняя (или 8я). Тут как раз тот случай, что самое последнее - не самое нужное (или совместимое).

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас буду пробовать